# Multiple jQuery Mobile at linked files

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I use jQuery mobile to make a mobile form and then submit it.

On the main page I import the jQuery libraries.

```
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
  <title>Waiter Menu</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="js1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js1.0/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

When submit the form from the first page and linked to the second, the libraries have pre-import and I don't want that.
Because at the second page I want to use custom JavaScript.
Is there any way not to stop jQuery at linked file?
Thanks in advance!!

---edit----

I found the solution here: [How To Disable Ajax In jQuery Mobile Before Page Load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684234/how-to-disable-ajax-in-jquery-mobile-before-page-load?answertab=active#tab-top)

i put this into form header

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
  });
</script>
```

and I set new header at second file!

Comment: You move to another #page or .html file? If .html file, add `data-ajax="false"` attribute to form div.

Comment: Ok add data-ajax=false as I mentioned.

Comment: you mean to do that?
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="new_order3.php" data-ajax="false" >
....if yes does not work

Comment: show us the head section of the secondpage.