# Disable AJAX page linking jQuery Mobile in Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, jquery-mobile

I use jQM in my Wordress site, raigle.net. I need to disable AJAX. How can I do that, knowing that jQM is loaded in functions.php?

This is my code to integrate jQM:

```
function custom_theme_files() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}


/* Incorporating jQuery Mobile */
function get_jqm() {


wp_enqueue_script(
 'jqm_js',
 'http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js',
 array('jquery'),
 '1.3.2'
 );

wp_register_style(
 'jqm_css',
 'http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css',
 '',
 '1.3.2'
 );
wp_enqueue_style(
 'jqm_css',
 'http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css',
 '',
 '1.3.2'
 );
 }
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'get_jqm');
```

I know, that somehow I should include this raw HTML before (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684234/how-to-disable-ajax-in-jquery-mobile-before-page-load)):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
</script>
```

How can I do that in Wordpress style?

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert the `mobileinit` event after jquery and before jquery mobile. See this post for explanation: [How To Disable Ajax In jQuery Mobile Before Page Load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684234/how-to-disable-ajax-in-jquery-mobile-before-page-load)

Also, best practice is to put your CSS files before your Javascript files.

Lastly, Wordpress already has jquery mobile ready to be called. Simply add: `wp_register_script( 'jquery.mobile' );`